# Graphics with fixed size boxes around formulas in HTML slides

Tags: boxes, pandoc, mathjax

I'm writing reveal.js slides using pandoc, and I need to include some simple graphics involving formulas within boxes of fixed size. Something like this, or just slightly more involved:

```
\begin{split}
\framebox[8em]{$x_1$}\framebox[12em]{$x_2$}\\
\framebox[15em]{$y_1$}\framebox[5em]{$y_2$}
\end{split}
```

Of course, I could build those as external PNG files (e.g. using LaTeXiT) to be included in my Markdown code, but I would like to avoid that, to increase clarity&reusability and also just to reduce the amount of external files I need.

So, my first instinct was to just write the graphics as a displayed equation, hoping that MathJax would deal with it nicely. However, MathJax does not support `\framebox`, sadly.

My second idea was using [CodeCogs scripts](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Clarge%20%5Cdpi%7B300%7D%5Cframebox[10em]%7BI%20need%20math%20here%7D) to convert LaTeX to PNG on the fly, but they won't support putting maths inside a `\framebox`; in fact, as soon as you use `$` or `\(…\)` delimiters, you get an "Invalid equation".

Third candidate, Google Chart API: [**does**](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5CHuge%20%5Cdisplaystyle%5Cfbox%7B$x_1$%7D) support formulas within a formula, does **not** support `\framebox`

Any more ideas?

Here's a screenshot for one of my slides, where the graphics was included as an external PNG:
[image: slides screenshot]

Comment: MathJax is off-topic here. But maybe you could give an example with your latex code to play with. Pandoc does support [several mechanisms for math in HTML](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math-rendering-in-html), maybe there is one, that works for you.

Comment: Thanks (why do we have a specific tag, if it's off-topic?)
Anyway: I'm already using MathJax for the formulas within my slides, and I can't switch to KaTeX or MathML because of other issues. The documentation you linked is indeed what inspired me to try CodeCogs.

Comment: Please make a fully compilable example and preferably a screenshot or mock-up of what you want

Comment: Perhaps a filter could do what you want. Have a look here: https://github.com/liamoc/latex-formulae